# Hard-coded hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, persistence

How would I hard-code a Configuration object in Hibernate? Here's what I have so far; I hope this gives you a gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(GenericMetadatable.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(SimpleMetadataValue.class);
    config.setProperty("connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver")
        .setProperty("connection.url", "jdbc:h2:~/test")
        .setProperty("connection.username", "sa")
        .setProperty("connection.password", "")
        .setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "TESTSCHEMA2")
        .setProperty("connection.pool_size", "2")
        .setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect")
        .setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread")
        .setProperty("cache.provider_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider")
        .setProperty("show_sql", "true");
    config.addProperties(new Properties() {{}});
    config.configure();
```

Comment: can you explain your problem properly

Comment: -1 You're not stating what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this:

```
config.addProperties(new Properties() {{}});
config.configure();
```

You can't have multiple configures.